How to setup a SLURM REST API Python client that uses --wrap functionality of sbatch?
The usage I'm trying to replicate from SLURM sbatch is the following:
JOB_NAME="hello-conda"
PARTITION="ram16cpu4"
N_JOBS=4

sbatch  -J ${JOB_NAME} -N 1 -p ${PARTITION} -c ${N_JOBS}  -o logs/${N}.out -e logs/${N}.err --export=ALL --wrap="${CMD}"

Here's the command I'm trying to test:
ENV="/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/efs/sandbox/sandbox/conda_environments/jolespin/sagemaker/VEBA-assembly_env/"
JOB_NAME="hello-conda"
CMD="source activate ${ENV} && (which python) > /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/efs/sandbox/sandbox/development/jolespin/Testing/SLURM-Test/hello_conda.txt"


slurm-client.py run -u jolespin -c="${CMD}" -p 4 -P ram16cpu4 -l /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/efs/sandbox/sandbox/development/jolespin/Testing/SLURM-Test/ -n ${JOB_NAME}

Here's how I'm calling the SLURM client:
        # Initialize SLURM client
        slurm_client = SLURMClient(base_url, user_token, user_key)

        # Define job parameters
        current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")

        environment =  {
            "PATH": os.environ["PATH"],
            "LD_LIBRARY_PATH": "/lib/:/lib64/:/usr/local/lib"
        }
        if args.env:
            environment["CUSTOM_ENV"] = args.env
            

        # Start the Slurm job and get the job ID
        job_id = slurm_client.start_job(
                    command=args.command, 
                    job_name=args.job_name, 
                    log_directory=args.log_directory,
                    num_cpus=args.num_cpus,
                    partition=args.partition,
                    export="ALL",
                    )

class SLURMClient:
    def __init__(self, base_url, token, username):
        self.base_url = base_url
        self.token = token
        self.username = username
        self.headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.token}',
            'X-SLURM-USER-NAME': self.username
        }

    def start_job(
        self, 
        command, 
        job_name, 
        log_directory,
        num_cpus,
        partition,
        environment,
        **kwargs,
        ):

        url = f'{self.base_url}/job'
        
        job_params = OrderedDict([
            ("name", job_name),
            ("account", "default"),
            ("standard_output", os.path.join(log_directory, f'{job_name}.out')),
            ("standard_error", os.path.join(log_directory, f'{job_name}.err')),
            ("ntasks", 1),
            ("cpus_per_task", num_cpus),
            ("partition", partition),
            ("export", "ALL"),
            ("wrap", command),
            ("environment", environment),
        ])
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            job_params[k] = v
        
        # Create a temporary script file with the command_string
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True, suffix=".sh", mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as f_script:
            # Make the script executable
            os.chmod(f_script.name, 0o755)
            
            # Shebang
            print("#!/bin/sh", file=f_script)
            # # Headers
            # for k, v in job_params.items():
            #     print("#SBATCH", f"--{k}={v}", file=f_script)
            # Command
            print(command, file=f_script)
            
            # Request
            paylod = {"job":job_params, "script":f_script.name}
            response = requests.post(url, headers=self.headers, json=paylod)

        
        if response.status_code == 200:
            job_response = response.json()
            job_id = job_response.get('job_id')
            print(f"Job {job_id} started successfully with {command}.")
            return job_id
        else:
            raise Exception(f'Failed to start job: {response.status_code} - {response.text}')

    def get_partitions(self):
        url = f'{self.base_url}/partitions'
        response = requests.get(url, headers=self.headers)
        
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return response.json()
        else:
            raise Exception(f'Failed to get partitions: {response.status_code} - {response.text}')

    def get_jobs(self):
        url = f'{self.base_url}/jobs'
        response = requests.get(url, headers=self.headers)
        
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return response.json().get('jobs', [])
        else:
            raise Exception(f'Failed to get jobs: {response.status_code} - {response.text}')
        
    def cancel_job(self, job_id):
        url = f'{self.base_url}/job/{job_id}'
        response = requests.delete(url, headers=self.headers)
        
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print(f"Job {job_id} canceled successfully.")
        else:
            raise Exception(f'Failed to cancel job {job_id}: {response.status_code} - {response.text}')


The REST API doesn't take in the same commands as sbatch unfortunately so if I run the above code I get the following:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/job_runner.py", line 93, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/job_runner.py", line 79, in main
    job_id = slurm_client.start_job(
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slurm_client/slurm_client.py", line 84, in start_job
    raise Exception(f'Failed to start job: {response.status_code} - {response.text}')
Exception: Failed to start job: 400 - {
   "meta": {
     "plugin": {
       "type": "openapi\/v0.0.37",
       "name": "Slurm OpenAPI v0.0.37"
     },
     "Slurm": {
       "version": {
         "major": 23,
         "micro": 7,
         "minor": 2
       },
       "release": "23.02.7"
     }
   },
   "errors": [
     {
       "description": "Disabled key: \"export\"",
       "error_number": 1,
       "error": "Operation not permitted",
       "source": "openapi specification"
     },
     {
       "error_code": 9001,
       "error": "Failure during parsing"
     }
   ]
 }

If I comment out export then I get an error with wrap:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/job_runner.py", line 93, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/job_runner.py", line 79, in main
    job_id = slurm_client.start_job(
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slurm_client/slurm_client.py", line 84, in start_job
    raise Exception(f'Failed to start job: {response.status_code} - {response.text}')
Exception: Failed to start job: 400 - {
   "meta": {
     "plugin": {
       "type": "openapi\/v0.0.37",
       "name": "Slurm OpenAPI v0.0.37"
     },
     "Slurm": {
       "version": {
         "major": 23,
         "micro": 7,
         "minor": 2
       },
       "release": "23.02.7"
     }
   },
   "errors": [
     {
       "description": "Disabled key: \"wrap\"",
       "error_number": 1,
       "error": "Operation not permitted",
       "source": "openapi specification"
     },
     {
       "error_code": 9001,
       "error": "Failure during parsing"
     }
   ]
 }

Commenting both those out, I was able to get it to run:
$ bash cmd_hello-conda.sh 
Job 206 started successfully with source activate /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/efs/sandbox/sandbox/conda_environments/jolespin/sagemaker/VEBA-assembly_env/ && (which python) > /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/efs/sandbox/sandbox/development/jolespin/Testing/SLURM-Test/hello_conda.txt.
Job hello-conda started successfully with ID: 206

When I check the status of the job:
$ slurm-client.py get jobs -u jolespin
 job_id        name partition   job_state  cpus                    nodes  submit_time  start_time   end_time                                                                                      standard_output                                                                                       standard_error user_name
    206 hello-conda ram16cpu4 CONFIGURING     4 ram16cpu4-dy-t16xlarge-1   1725063561  1725063562 1756599562 /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/efs/sandbox/sandbox/development/jolespin/Testing/SLURM-Test/hello-conda.out /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/efs/sandbox/sandbox/development/jolespin/Testing/SLURM-Test/hello-conda.err  jolespin


However, once it runs it just fails. And doesn't make the output files.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? My main goal is to replicate the sbatch command in the first code block using the REST API.
